# Is there a setting to control word definition for faster navigation in IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea, clojure, cursive

Clojure words like `when-let` are hyphenated. When using IntelliJ Idea word navigation, this symbol is treated as 3 words, which makes navigation very slow. Is there a setting for handling Clojure symbols and keywords as words, or some better way to navigate Clojure words?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe there's a way built in. You may be able to write your own plugin to add some navigation actions. There are also some tickets in JetBrains's YouTrack system that are related:

- [IDEA-155038](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-155038): "select word" definition
- [IDEA-68325](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-68325): Add actions for move caret to beginning/end of next/previous words.

You could vote for or comment on those tickets, or create your own if what you're looking for exactly is different from them.